# vue add router replaced everything in App.vue

Tags: vue.js

I wanted to use vue router in my project so I ran:

```
vue add router
```

By doing that it added the folder router to my project but at the same time replaced everything I had in the `App.vue`

Is there a way I can get back what I lost?

Comment: Are you using version control such as git? if not why not. if you are, `git reset --hard && git clean -f -d`

Comment: I just started the project, so I wasn't using git, otherwise I would've just used git to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

you can always try with ctrl + z to go back in changes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).